R ggplot and exceeding stack size
I am using R to display some polygons on a map. Polygons are stored in a geoJson file and there are many of them (around 1000). In some geojson files may be even much more.
Here is the R program reading the geojson file and drawing polygons on a map:
library ("ggplot2")
library ("sf")
library ("rnaturalearth")
library ("rnaturalearthdata")
library ("ggspatial")
library ("geojsonR")

europe <- ne_countries (continent = "europe", scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class (europe)

p <- ggplot (data = europe)
p <- p + geom_sf ()

js <- FROM_GeoJson (url_file_string = "file.geojson")

i <- 0
for (f in js$features) {
    if (!is.null (f$properties$InterferenceLevel)) {
        if (i < 250) {
            #print (f$properties$InterferenceLevel)
            #print (f$geometry$coordinates)
            overlay_polygon <- f$geometry$coordinates
            overlay_polygon <- sf::st_polygon (list(f$geometry$coordinates))
            #print (overlay_polygon)
            poly <- sf::st_as_sfc (list (overlay_polygon), crs = 4326)

            p <- p + geom_sf (data = poly, fill=alpha ("red", 0.2), color=alpha ("red", 0.2))
        }
        i <- i + 1
        #print (i)
    }
}

p <- p + coord_sf(xlim = c(-20, 42), ylim = c(35, 72))
plot (p)

The problem I have is that if I want to draw all polygons in that way, the program stops and reports
Error: C stack usage  7970756 is too close to the limit

I have added another condition involving a counter to see how many polygons I can draw. At 250 the map is shown. If I go higher, I get the error message.
Does anybody has an idea of another way to draw transparent polygons over the map in a way that does not fill up the stack size? I do not have much experience with ggplot. I have been using charts with tens of thousands of dots without problems and here I cannot draw more than a couple of hundreds polygons. I am sure there is a way to do it. I just don't know how to add them to the map once it is shown in a window. It does not have to be ggplot if it can be done with some other function.

It looks like you are adding a full geom_sf layer to the plot each time, rather than collecting your polygons into a single object and drawing a single geom_sf using that. This may be your problem, but it is difficult to tell without a [mre]. Perhaps include a link to a geoJSON that reproduces your problem?

Its not sf as such, you can't have so many items in a ggplot. This loop adds a single data point using geom_point and prints a counter until it falls over:
p = ggplot()
i = 1
while(TRUE){
 p = p + geom_point(data=data.frame(x=runif(1),y=runif(1)),aes(x=x,y=y))
 message(i);i=i+1
}

For me this runs until 878 and then I get Error: C stack usage  7974740 is too close to the limit
Solution is to amass your data into a single data frame and add it with one geom_ call.
If you need to colour or style them in some way, keep that in the data frame too, and specify that attribute not as an aes() but as a vector parameter, eg:
geom_sf(all_my_polys, col=all_my_polys$colour)


Each polygon I add is a closed polygon which is colored. Should I add all polygons to an array of polygons. There are three possible colors for polygons. Do you think it would be ok to just have three arrays of polygons, and draw each array with its color?

Thanks. I made it with your suggestion.

If its a true geojson file the right thing to do is probably read it into an sf object with st_read and then deal with it as a data frame.

Thanks your suggestion helped to make it much simpler.
